# How to upload file on server with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying for several hours to upload files to my local server folder `upload`, but is being harder than expected, please help.

Below my front end to insert files `form.hbs`

```html
<form action="/editcrew/" method="POST" encType="multipart/form-data" novalidate></form>
<input type="file" name="profile_image">
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" style="margin:90px 0 0 0">Submit</button>
```

Here below my controller `export.update` located inside the file `userController.js` which successfully inserts the name of the file into MySql database.

```js
exports.update = (req, res) => {
    
    const { first_name, last_name, profile_image } = req.body;

   

    connection.query('UPDATE user SET first_name=? ,last_name=?, profile_image=? ', [first_name, last_name, profile_image, req.params.id], (err, rows) => {
        if (!err) {
            connection.query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = ?', [req.params.id], (err, rows) => {
                //when done with the connection release it
                // connection.release();
                if (!err) {
                    res.render('edit-crew', { rows, alert: `${first_name} has been updated.` });
                } else {
                    console.log(err);
                }
                console.log('The data from user table:\n', rows);
            });
        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log('The data from user table:\n', rows);
    });
};
```

Here below is the router for the `post` requests.

```js
router.post('/editcrew/:id',userController.update);
```

For reference my `app.js`

```js
const express = require("express");
const exphbs = require("express-handlebars");
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');

// const userContoller = require('./controllers/userController')
// to be removed when deployed in heroku

require("dotenv").config();
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');



// Parsing middleware
const app = express();

// default option
app.use(fileUpload());

//to load static file
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.static("upload"));
//Listen on port 5000
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false })); //To parse URL-encoded bodies (as sent by HTML forms)

app.use(express.json()); //To parse the incoming requests with JSON bodies
app.use(cookieParser());

app.engine("hbs", exphbs({ extname: ".hbs" }));//Templating engine to change the extenion of file from .handlebar to .hbs
app.set("view engine", "hbs");


//link which tell to the server express.js to get the routeing from user.js
// const routes = require('./server/routes/user');
app.use("/", require('./routes/user'));
app.use('/auth', require('./routes/auth'));


const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

My goal is to have the controller `update` to not only insert name file on MySql database but also upload the file inside the local folder `/upload`

Comment: this video may help, it demonstrate how to upload binary files using multer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d8COHTGz2cc

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to upload file to the server and save the file . I would recommend you to use "multer" with expressjs . If you need extra features you can customize it .
You can read the doc and start using it .
[here is the doc](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/multer.html)

Comment: Hi, I've tried to use multer, but I was not able to apply it to my code. I re-thought the problem and opened another question here with what I achieved so far: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70305822/how-to-simultaneously-upload-file-on-server-and-file-name-on-mysql-with-node-js