# How to simultaneously upload file on server and file name on Mysql with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I`m working on my CRUD app.

- I've created an user controller which upload file name to Mysql database on `userController.js`.
- I've created ,using the express file upload library, a file uploader to the server folder 'upload'.

Here is the front end, on `edit-crew.hbs` :

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
  <form action="/editcrew" method="POST" encType="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
    <input type="file" name="profile_image">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
  </form>
</div>
```

My issue is that I'm not able to combine this two process together. The route is handled as follow:

```js
router.post('/editcrew/:id',userController.update);
```

But is also handled on app.js as follows:

```js
app.post('/editcrew', (req, res) => {
  let profile_image;
  let uploadPath;

  if (!req.files || Object.keys(req.files).length === 0) {
    return res.status(400).send('No files were uploaded.');
  }

  // name of the input is sampleFile
  profile_image = req.files.profile_image;
  uploadPath = __dirname + '/upload/' + profile_image.name;

  // Use mv() to place file on the server
  profile_image.mv(uploadPath, function (err) {
    if (err) return res.status(500).send(err);

    else {
      if (!err) {
        res.json(`${profile_image.name} has been uploaded.`);

      } else {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

What is the best way to combine these two processes together upload files on the server and file names on database?

for reference here below the `userController.js` which query the database and insert the filename:

```js
exports.update = (req, res) => {
    
    const { first_name, last_name, profile_image } = req.body;

   

    connection.query('UPDATE user SET first_name=? ,last_name=?, profile_image=? ', [first_name, last_name, profile_image, req.params.id], (err, rows) => {
        if (!err) {
            connection.query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = ?', [req.params.id], (err, rows) => {
                //when done with the connection release it
                // connection.release();
                if (!err) {
                    res.render('edit-crew', { rows, alert: `${first_name} has been updated.` });
                } else {
                    console.log(err);
                }
                console.log('The data from user table:\n', rows);
            });
        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log('The data from user table:\n', rows);
    });
};
```

Any help or hints on the right path is highly appreciated!!

Comment: IMO, there is a fileStore service that stores the files just like you do, and stores the fileName, ID and other stuff on its own mysql table. Now if you want to link an uploaded file to a user, use the ID received from the fileStore service. I would refactor your upload part in your app.js into the service, and your endpoint would request the service to save/store `req.files.profile_image`

Comment: Hi, this fileStore service has a particular name, can be installed through npm? or I misunderstand your answer?

Comment: The service is yours to create... You have controllers, you have views, and usually services/models to play with the data.

Comment: Ok, so basically I should refract the code and eliminate the route handling on `app.post` in `app.js` and integrate that handling on the `export.update` function. I will look more into it...